# Remove default route on AlmaLinux 9 / RH9

Tags: rhel, network-interface, iproute, alma-linux

I'm running AlmaLinux 9 (a red hat 9 clone), and I would like to permanently remove a default route.  My routing table is shown below, and I would like to remove the 172.31.252.1 route.

I know how to temporarily remove a route with 'ip route' command but it always appears on next boot.  Instead, I want to permanently remove this route.  The old RH /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts directory is no longer used (but kept for legacy reasons).  I started a GUI but nowhere in the Network settings GUI do I see a default route setup.

How do I permanently remove that route?

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.252.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens256
0.0.0.0         172.31.254.1    0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 ens192
172.31.252.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens256
172.31.254.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 ens192
```

The ManagementLan interface is stored in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections, while EntertainmentVlan is stored in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-link:

```
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME="Entertainment VLAN 30"
UUID=85810e29-e837-1d48-f5e7-9cd60d5a0ee4
IPADDR=172.31.252.31
PREFIX=24
DNS1=172.31.254.4
DOMAIN=mydomain.com
DNS2=172.31.234.4
HWADDR=00:0C:29:B6:49:0E
```

ip route:

```
default via 172.31.254.1 dev ens192 proto static metric 100
default via 172.31.252.1 dev ens256 proto static metric 101
172.31.252.0/24 dev ens256 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.252.31 metric 101
172.31.254.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.254.31 metric 100
```

ip rule show:

```
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Comment: Have you gone through `nmcli` ?  For example. `nmcli conn show` ? Then Identify your connection, after that you should run `nmcli con modify <your_connectioN_name> -ipv4.routes "0.0.0.0/0 172.31.252.1 100"`  Subsequently run `nmcli conn reload` or `nmcli conn up <your_connection_name>`.  For more details see: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/configuring-static-routes_configuring-and-managing-networking

Comment: Have also a look at: `nmcli -f NAME,DEVICE,FILENAME conn show`.  Other fields can be found in `man nmcli`

Comment: I tried the above and the second default route is still present.  Using nmcli  con show <id> I see that there are NO ipv4.routes present.  Does that mean something else is adding the route to the routing table?  I also set ipv4.never-default=yes but no change in routes after NetworkManager service restart

Comment: I see you are running `netstat -rn`  , can you show the output of `ip route` and `ip rule show` ?

Comment: ok question updated.  The second command you suggested allowed me to correct my questions, the EntertainmentVLAN interface is stored in a legacy ifcfg file, but it's DEFROUTE=no

Comment: Solved: something above worked.  I thought restarting the NetworkManager service would apply all changes, but it doesn't.   I again had to run nmcli con reload and then things worked.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear it worked. I had that line in the first comment.